# Python - Save all 'available' elements in Json and print it afterwards when all search is finished?

Tags: python, json

So I have been working abit with json and just improving the knowledge with it basically.

What I want to do is that I save all these numbers that are available etc on a list or whatever you might think of.

The Json:

```
{
    "threads": [
        {
            "seoTitle": "trucks",
            "other_crap": "it's a fox!"
        },
        {
            "seoTitle": "rockets",
            "other_crap": "i'm rocket man"
        },
        {
            "seoTitle": "helicopter",
            "other_crap": "for 007",
            "skus": [
                {
                    "Number": "7",
                    "available": true
                },
                {
                    "Number": "7.5",
                    "available": true
                },
                {
                    "Number": "8",
                    "available": false
                },
                {
                    "Number": "8.5",
                    "available": true
                },
                {
                    "Number": "9",
                    "available": true
                },
                {
                    "Number": "9.5",
                    "available": false
                },
                {
                    "Number": "10",
                    "available": true
                },
                {
                    "Number": "10.5",
                    "available": false
                },
                {
                    "Number": "11",
                    "available": true
                },
                {
                    "Number": "11.5",
                    "available": false
                },
                {
                    "Number": "12",
                    "available": true
                },
                {
                    "Number": "12.5",
                    "available": false
                },
                {
                    "Number": "13",
                    "available": true
                }
            ],
            "restricted": false,
            "subtitle": "Stackoverflow"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see from the Json file there is **skus** and below that there is different Number and available and what I want to do is that I want to print all the **NUMBERS** based on IF it is **available** meaning if its available then print it out or save it into a list and then print it out when it has search all of the and if it is **not** available then just skip to next one. -  That is what my goal is - The problem is that I don't know what I should do based through a json file, How can I possible make it so it knows what to save into a list based on *available* ?

1) *what your expected output is,*

I expect a output that might look like:

```
helicopter
for 007
7
7.5
8.5
9
10
11
12
13
```

2) *what you have tried so far,*

Right now I have only printed out seoTitle and other_crap

```
print(threads['seoTitle'])
print(threads['other_crap'])
```

3) *why what you've tried isn't working*

I have tried to do a for loop which I totally failed with doing

```
for element in threads['skus']:
    if element not 'available'
```

basically failed :/

code that I am using:

```
old_list = []

while True:
    try:
        resp = requests.get(url)
        new_list = resp.json()['threads']

        for item in new_list:
            if item['seoTitle']not in old_list:
                try:


                    print(item['seoTitle']) 
                    print(item['other_crap']) 


                    itemskus = item.get('skus', {})
                    if itemskus:
                        for element in item['skus']:
                            print(element)
                    else:
                        print('Item skus could not be found')


                    old_list.append(['seoTitle'])



                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    print("ERROR")
                    time.sleep(5)
                    continue


        else:
            randomtime = random.randint(4, 60)
            time.sleep(randomtime)


    except Exception as e:
        continue
```

For now this is my output:

```
helicopter
for 007
{"Number": "7", "available": true }
{"Number": "7.5", "available": true }
{"Number": "8", "available": false }
{"Number": "8.5","available": true }
{"Number": "9", "available": true}
{"Number": "9.5", "available": false}
{"Number": "10", "available": true}
{"Number": "10.5", "available": false }
{"Number": "11", "available": true}
{"Number": "11.5","available": false }
{"Number": "12","available": true }
{"Number": "12.5", "available": false}
{"Number": "13", "available": true }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please show us: 1) what your expected output is, 2) what you have tried so far, 3) why what you've tried isn't working

Comment: @ResetACK Ok I will edit it as a post now :)

Comment: The `sample` that you provided it not correct (or not complete). If you try copy/paste it in a notebook you get a syntax error. Please update

Comment: @kosnik Oh im sorry, I have updated it now :)

Comment: Please edit your post to include all of your code. What errors (if any) do you get with your current code.

Comment: @ResetACK Will update it now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to import the `json` into a python `dict`. Say that your file is called `my_sample.json` then you do

```
import json
with open('my_sample.json') as f:
    sample = json.load(f)
```

Now, `sample` is a dict that contain your `json` data. You want to access the `skus` of the 3rd thread in the list of threads, provided that this is available. You can achieve this by creating the following list

```
available_skus = [float(d['Number']) for d in sample['threads'][2]['skus'] if d['available']]
```

Then print what you need

```
print(sample['threads'][2]['seoTitle'])
for el in available_skus:
    print(el)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
helicopter
7
7.5
8.5
9
10
11
12
13
```

**EDIT**

If you are not sure that the `skus` information is always on the 3rd thread you can substitute `available_skus` with the following

```
available_skus = [d['Number'] for thread in sample['threads'] if 'skus' in thread.keys() for d in thread['skus'] if d['available']]
```

Comment: Oh im getting an error saying `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '7.5'` though..

Comment: Should I just change int to float instead maybe?

Comment: yes, my bad it should be `float`. You can even remove it altogether if you do not mind `string`

Comment: Awesome! I can confirm that this helped me and I do appreciate it alot! Thank you many many many many times!